# Use `Apply` on an expression based on its `Head`

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions

I am making an expression into a list.
Depending on the simplifications etc. using `List@@` can be problematic.

Eg.

```
 expr= (-2 + 4 tk + 2 t (-1 + 2 tl) w^2)/(1 + t w^2)
```

I want to make this **product of terms** into a list by doing `List@@expr` which is fine as it should result into the following list:

```
{1/(1 + t w^2), -2 + 4 tk + 2 t (-1 + 2 tl) w^2}
```

However, say I first want to do a `FullSimplification` of the input expression and after that, I want to make it a list as before.

```
 List@@(expr//FullSimplify)
 ={-2, 4 tl, (4 (tk - tl))/(1 + t w^2)}
```

Now the `FullSimplification` has made the expression a sum of terms

```
(expr//FullSimplify)
 = -2 + 4 tl + (4 (tk - tl))/(1 + t w^2)
```

And now the use of `List@@` will give a **wrong** list. So this can be dangerous when one does not look into the final expression carefully before applying `List@@`.

Probably one way to make sure the input is always in the form of multiplication of terms is to provide a condition that sees the `Head` as `Times` before applying `List@@` on it.

**Or is there any better fail-safe procedure for using `List@@`?**

Comment: `Simplify /@ (List @@ (expr // Simplify // Together))` will give you three factors since there is a common factor of `2`

Comment: What about: `If[Head[expr] == Times, List @@ expr]`

Comment: @DanielHuber, yes this is what I am doing.

Comment: `Power @@@ FactorList[expr]` will list the factors, which may not be what you want. But since you're willing to `FullSimplify` the `expr` (for who knows how that will transform it), maybe it is.